# Downloading rasters from ArcGIS image service when Download Rasters grayed out

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, download, image-service

I am trying to download individual rasters from an ArcGIS image service. The [data](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=ba1c287a56b342319753cee029e2dbfc) is offered by ArcGIS Online as a .pitem or .pitemx file to be opened in ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro (respectively). The rasters represent a collection of chlorophyll data from different months over 21 years. I need the individual rasters in order to do some summary statistics. In both ArcMap 10.7 and ArcGIS Pro 2.2, "Download Rasters" option in the table of contents is grayed out. I have also tried the "Download Rasters" tool, but there are no options for building an SQL statement to select the rasters. I need to download all of the rasters in the collection anyway, so there is no need to select by criteria. However, it seems like this is required as the tool will not work without an SQL statement.

Is there a workaround to download the individual monthly rasters?

[image: Download Rasters TOC menu]

[image: Download Rasters Tool dialogue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [commented by @user30184](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/438069/downloading-rasters-from-arcgis-image-service-when-download-rasters-grayed-out/439714#comment715140_438069):

> By looking at the service metadata
> https://oceans5.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/chlorophyll/chlorophyll_sub1_monthly_deviation/ImageServer
> downloads are not allowed and workarounds would be illegal.